# AWS configured RDS mysql DB instance with VPC

Tags: node.js

In my AWS nodejs project, I have created a lambda function which needs to access AWS RDS mysql. Have configured mysql DB instance with VPC. On execution, below statement is giving error "Cannot find module 'mysql'"

var mysql=require('mysql');

Please suggest, if we need to explicitly upload nodejs mysql module to lambda function. My code runs properly in my local setup.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: {
  "errorMessage": "Cannot find module 'mysql'",
  "errorType": "Error",
  "stackTrace": [
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)",
    "Module.require (module.js:497:17)",
    "require (internal/module.js:20:19)",
    "Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:4:13)",
    "Module._compile (module.js:570:32)",
    "Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)",
    "Module.load (module.js:487:32)",
    "tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)",
    "Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)"
  ]
}

Comment: have u installed mysql module? npm install mysql --save

Comment: i am directly working on lambda function.there is no option for add the libraries. RDS mysql is also on aws that should be connect.